# Problema al probar un servicio web SOAP

Tags: java, soap, struts

Estoy implementando un servicio web SOAP en Java en una aplicación que usa Struts en la capa de presentación y tengo problemas para probarlo. El IDE que estoy usando es Netbeans y el servicio lo realicé usando el asistente que provee el IDE. La aplicación despliega correctamente en un servidor GlassFish y el servicio web que estoy implementando se expone de forma adecuada. La dirección del WSDL generado es:

http://localhost:8080/Medicamentos/webServices/TestWSDL?WSDL

El inconveniente ocurre cuando deseo probar el servicio cambiando la URL a http://localhost:8080/Medicamentos/webServices/TestWSDL?Tester, link que debería mostrarme una página para ingresar los datos necesarios para probar el servicio, pero me redirige a la página de información del endpoint (http://localhost:8080/Medicamentos/webServices/TestWSDL). En el archivo struts.xml ya le he indicado a Struts que excluya las rutas /webServices/* para que estas sean manejadas por el servlet encargado del servicio web:

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/webServices/.*"/>
```

Mi archivo web.xml:

```xml
<display-name>Medicamentos</display-name>
<!-- Spring/Hibernate conf -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!--Struts filter and interceptor -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Sticky session -->
<distributable/>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestWSDL</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestWSDL</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webServices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

¿Algo adicional debo agregar para excluir la URL y poder probar el servicio web o tengo algo mal en las expresiones regulares?. Ya probé el servicio usando SoapUI y similares, pero me gustaría poder realizar las pruebas desde el navegador a través de la URL.

Comment: Antes que nada, te recomendaría hacer la prueba de desplegar el Webservice en otra aplicación web. Respecto a tu pregunta, para entender que está pasando, podrías incrementar el nivel de logging a debug del paquete org.apache.struts2.dispatcher y la salida de logging podría indicarte si está pasando algo que no estás contemplando al llamar a la URL del servicio SOAP.

Comment: Estás seguro que esa URL debiera mostrar el formulario?

Comment: Realicé la prueba aumentando el nivel de debug en Struts y no hay ningún inconveniente, la petición de la URL no pasa por allí, como deberia ocurrir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glassfish utiliza internamente el *servlet* **`org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet`**. Este busca dos *strings* en el *query-string* de la URL de la petición:

- ***`endpoint`*** **`?` `Tester`**: Este reenvía la petición hacia otro *servlet*, `org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet`, el cual genera un cliente con `wsimport` a partir del WSDL obtenido con una petición agregando `?WSDL` a la URL y **genera** el HTML para la página de prueba.
- ***`endpoint`*** **`?` `WSDL`**: Este genera el WSDL usando una instancia de `com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamWriterFactory` y lo escribe en la petición.

No obstante, en tu caso, has registrado el `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` y el `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet`, el cual no tiene *esa* opción.

Si el Glassfish que estás utilizando soporta Java EE 6 o superior, basta con que anotes la clase que implementa el servicio web con `@WebService` sin necesidad de *mapear* algún *servlet*. Y entonces tendrás disponible la página de prueba.*

<sup>────────────

* Es importante deshabilitar esta opción en ambientes productivos, ya se a través del archivo `sun-web.xml` o `sun-ejb-jar.xml` especificando `false` en el elemento `debugging-enabled`.</sup>

Comment: Eliminé las declaraciones de los servlets del `web.xml`. Mi servicio ya tenía declarada la anotación `@WebService`. Funcionó correctamente, gracias.